# EJS: if this then show length

Tags: javascript, node.js, ejs

Let's say I have MySQL database with NodeJS and EJS.

In my database I have 3 rules: `OK`, `WARNING` and `FALSE`. 
How to get how many of ok's, warning's and false's do I have in database?

I tried something like this

[image]

The result is this

[image]

In blue it's TOTAL and in green should be how many good are out of TOTAL

[image]

Comment: what is `results`?

Answer (score 0):

Try filtering the results array and get the length of it.

```
<span class="count">
  <p><%- results.filter(r => r === 'OK').length %></p>
</span>
```

How about filtering the array before you call the template? Keep that complexity out of the template itself.

Comment: Thanks for help but it didn't work. Any other ideas?

Comment: I've updated my question. I've added pic. of the database. I want to filter results depending on FLAG Column

Comment: How about doing the filtering before passing it to the template?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your help sorxrob. I did it the way u told me to :)

It may not me the cleanest way but it's working.

Here is 
[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vY6Wu.png)

Here is
[Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MypmP.png)